# Zoom Image with Drawing on Panel in C#

Tags: c#, image, zooming, panel

I use a scaled down version of an image and do some drawing on it based on mouse events. I update the result on the panel by setting its `.BackgroundImage` property. The following is the code.

```
private void repaint()
{
    Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
        {
            // Loads a large image from file
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(images[currentImage]);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            g.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
            imgWoP = 0.24f * img.Width;
            imgHoP = 0.24f * img.Height;
            float trans_x = panel1.Width / 2 - imgWoP / 2;
            float trans_y = panel1.Height / 2 - imgHoP / 2;
            // Draw a scaled version in the center of the panel
            g.DrawImage(img, trans_x, trans_y, imgWoP, imgHoP);
            // Do some drawing here
            g.DrawLine(...)
            g.DrawEllipse(...)
        }
    }
    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        panel1.BackgroundImage = buffer;
    }));
    });
}
```

Now, I need to zoom into this image which includes the graphics. I also need *the co-ordinates of the graphics* which I draw as the zoom changes. I could simply zoom the final bitmap before setting it as the `BackgroundImage` but then I do not get any scrollbars so that I am able to see the entire image. I've set `AutoScroll` to true.

Comment: So what is the question? You can scale the graphics you draw by scaling the Graphics object: g.ScaleTransform.

Comment: How do I scroll in the Panel then?

Comment: The simplest way is to put the panel in another one, which has autoscroll=true. No control can scroll (with scrollbars) without any other nested control that goes over its bounds.

Comment: Con you post this as an answer with a bit detailed explanation?

Comment: Not sure which part needs explaining. And also not quite sure of the whole task. and the whole is a bit long for a coded answer..I would consider displaying the large image in a PictureBox, which does the zooming for you. Then make sure the Paint event uses a scaled Graphics object with the same zoom factor. And the Mouseevent calculates each location into a scaled point. And finally put the PB into an autoscrolling Panel. If you want the combined image, i.e. Image plus the drawing from the Paint event you can get it via PB.DrawToBitmap..